# Why rancher to create virtual cluster in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, rancher

Manifest(yml) with kubernetes resource type(`kind: Namespace`) can be  applied through `kubectl` to create a virtual cluster

In our environment, manifest yaml's are applied using `kubectl` to create kubernetes resource types(deployment, service, autoscaling, ingress) under the given namespace

But, [rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/cluster-admin/projects-and-namespaces/#about-namespaces) is used to create kubernetes resource type(`kind: Namespace` virtual cluster).

---

What is the advantage of creating kubernetes resource type(`Namespace`) using rancher? instead of a manifest yaml applied through `kubectl`

Answer (score 2):

Rancher uses concept of "Project" which is not present in "vanilla" kubernetes, which allows you to assign RBAC roles, PodSecurityPolicy etc to a group of namespaces in easy way.

If you are not using rancher to create projects and namespaces - you have to assign all these Roles and PSPs by yourself. For example, if you have default restricted policy on your cluster, namespace created by `kubectl create namespace foo` won't be able to run any pods by default, see https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/admin-settings/pod-security-policies/

> Namespaces that are not assigned to projects do not inherit PSPs, regardless of whether the PSP is assigned to a cluster or project. Because these namespaces have no PSPs, workload deployments to these namespaces will fail, which is the default Kubernetes behavior.

To sum it up, namespaces can be created using `kubectl create namespace` or manifests, but it might be cumbersome to make it all work well. Using rancher to provision namespaces is easier to maintain and troubleshoot.

As for advantages, having ability to group namespaces under "project" and assign resources, PSP and roles to a group of namespaces with rancher UI support is one of the main selling points of having rancher in a first place. `Namespace` objects  themselves are basically the same as anywhere else.